# Php-fpm causes postfix to send mails from root@myDomain to root@myDomain

Tags: php, linux, email

The issue is that I receive `bounce back` error in `mail.log` when PHP tries to run some scripts.

I've looked through `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Feb 13 12:09:01 myUserName CRON[11111]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Feb 13 12:39:02 myUserName postfix/pickup[27697]: 48E243F4E2: uid=0 from=<root>
Feb 13 12:39:02 myUserName postfix/cleanup[28826]: 48E243F4E2: message-id=<20160213123902.48E243F4E2@myDomain.com>
Feb 13 12:39:02 myUserName postfix/qmgr[27698]: 48E243F4E2: from=<root@myDomain.com>, size=732, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 13 12:39:02 myUserName postfix/virtual[28828]: 48E243F4E2: to=<root@myDomain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=virtual, delay=0.17, delays=0.12/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "root@myDomain.com")
```

Why is this happening? How should I prevent it? It is cluttering my log files.

---

**EDIT1:**

I use `php-fpm` and Content of `maxlifetime` is:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e

max=1440

if which php5 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    for sapi in apache2 apache2filter cgi fpm; do
        if [ -e /etc/php5/${sapi}/php.ini ]; then
            cur=$(php5 -c /etc/php5/${sapi}/php.ini -d "error_reporting='~E_ALL'" -r 'print ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");')
            [ -z "$cur" ] && cur=0
            [ "$cur" -gt "$max" ] && max=$cur
        fi
    done
else
    for ini in /etc/php5/*/php.ini /etc/php5/conf.d/*.ini; do
        cur=$(sed -n -e 's/^[[:space:]]*session.gc_maxlifetime[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/p' $ini 2>/dev/null || true);
        [ -z "$cur" ] && cur=0
        [ "$cur" -gt "$max" ] && max=$cur
    done
fi

echo $(($max/60))

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The script always produces output, so when you run it from cron, cron will mail the output to the owner of the crontab.

There are a few things you can do about this:

You could set MAILTO=youraddress@example.com in the crontab to tell cron where to send the mail.

You could modify the script to not output anything.

You could tell cron to discard the output of the script e.g. using >/dev/null or similar.

P.S. this question probably doesn't belong here. Maybe serverfault or superuser would br more appropriate.

Comment: How should I modify the script to not output anything? What part of the script needs to be changed?

Comment: Actually I don't run this script. I don't know why `php-fpm` runs this script and for what reason.